# SSH public key denied Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, kali-linux

am not able to ssh to Amazon AWS from my kali nethunter device nexus 6p I get this error public key denied.

However I can easily ssh from my desktop without any issues, computer that has kali linux directly installed.

Here is the error.

──(rootkali)-[/sdcard/Download]
└─# ssh -i kali-cloud.pem ec2user@ec2-x-x-x-x.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0660 for 'kali-cloud.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "kali-cloud.pem": bad permissions
ec2user@ec2-x-x -x.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Kindly suggest.

Regards
Skorp

Comment: I suggest reading the error message. It clearly says that your key's permissions are not suitable. As a result, key-based authentication fails.

Answer (score 1):

Private keys should be go-rw and public keys should be go-w at least.
In other words, permission 0660 is bad.  chmod go-rw  or 0600

Note also that the parent directory must also not be writable to anyone but the owner, so it should be 700 or 750

The reasoning here:

- A private key is pretty useless if it is readable to others.
- Both public key or private key are pretty useless if they can just be rewritten by others, either directly, or by replacing the file in the directory.

It would be a security hole to *not* ignore them when either of these is possible.

Comment: Initially after getting keys from AWS I gave permission chmod 400 for kali-cloud.pem. now even after chmod go-rw it's not working same error

Comment: Very likely the directory also has wrong permissions.  I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the permission of your .pem file using this command:

> chmod 400 kali-cloud.pem

Second you have to use the correct username to connect with your ec2 instance i.e **ec2-user** instead of ec2user:

> ──(rootkali)-[/sdcard/Download] └─# ssh -i kali-cloud.pem ec2user@ec2-x-x-x-x.us-